# Change input text value if it is NaN using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to change value of textbox to -999, if it is having a value of NaN. I have written some code but it is not working, please suggest me what I need to change in this.

```js
if($('input[name="tt10"]').val() === NaN) {
$('input[name="tt10"]').val('-999');
}
```

```html
<input name='tt10' value='NaN'>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your edit is still incomplete - ".val()" gives a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `.val()` to get the value of the input. And since the value is a string, you need to compare it with a string.

```js
if($('input[name="tt10"]').val() === 'NaN') {
    $('input[name="tt10"]').val('-999');
};
```

```html
<input name='tt10' value='NaN'>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `.val()` to get value from `input field`.
Like this:

```
$('input[name="tt10"]').val()
```

And with that value now, you can check if value of input is `NaN` or not:

```
if($('input[name="tt10"]').val() === 'NaN') {
    $('input[name="tt10"]').val('-999');
};
```

For more information you can visit [official documentation](https://api.jquery.com/val/).